# How to disable warning: [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed

Tags: mysql

I do not use secured connection in my MySQL server v8.0.21.
Is there a possibility to disable the warning:

```
[Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the public part of the certificate, import it as trusted certificate to the target machine. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Add [`skip-ssl=1`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ssl) to your `my.cnf` config file.